# USB Flash Drive - Code: Cannot open because not a supported file type or damaged file

Tags: usb-flash-drive

I have a 4GB USB Flash Drive. How do I access, in a discernible format, a file/file folder which reads: "Could not open ABC file because it is either not a supported file type or because file has been damaged (for example, it was sent as an email attachment and wasn’t correctly decoded)."

The file is not deleted, it just appears as a blank page. I have tried several data recovery programs - didn’t work. Looked at multiple You Tube videos, none of which covers how to decode an encrypted file.  It is a folder with multiple documents. The entire folder is not accessible. I have tried pdf, word and excel.  Folder does not show a tag file such as .pdf, .doc, xlsx, etc.  I can see on the lower left corner that it shows multiple pages, but can’t get to it.  I have other documents on the flash drive which I can still access.

When I look to open with Word, what shows under the file conversion is   Windows (default)       MS-DOS             Other encoding.  Under the preview window directly below it information shows encrypted.

I have tried different readers and computers and the same blank document appears.

HELP!!!

Comment: What program is giving the "could not open" message?

Comment: Maybe add a screenshot of what you see?

Comment: Which operating system are you using? When did the problem start? Were you able to open this file on the flash drive on this computer before you noticed the problem? Why do you think the file is encrypted? Which software did you use to encrypt it? What program did you use to create this file? Along with showing a screenshot of the error like @Paul requested, please also include a screenshot of the properties of the file. You can access the properties of the file by right-clicking on the file and go to properties. Please comment back letting us know if you do not know how to take a screenshot.